# i save invoice The name of the product does not appear in the report and the database, but the ID number of the Product appears

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public JsonResult SaveClientOrder(Sale sale, List<SalesDetail> salesDetails)
{
    NeamahBranch.Helper.AppHelper.ReturnMessage retMessage = new AppHelper.ReturnMessage();
    InvoiceBranchs_DBEntities db = new InvoiceBranchs_DBEntities();
    retMessage.IsSuccess = true;
    foreach (var item in salesDetails)
    {
        sale.SalesDetails.Add(new SalesDetail { ProductId = item.ProductId, UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice, Quantity = item.Quantity, LineTotal = item.LineTotal });
    }
    db.Sales.Add(sale);enter image description here
    retMessage.Messagae = "Save Success!";
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        retMessage.IsSuccess = false;
    }
    return Json(retMessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I have read the title 5 times and I still have no idea what you are trying to do or what the problem is... read [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you've forgot to add the **name** field

```
    foreach (var item in salesDetails)
    {
        sale.SalesDetails.Add(new SalesDetail { Name= item.Name, ProductId = item.ProductId, UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice, Quantity = item.Quantity, LineTotal = item.LineTotal });
    }
```

Comment: I have relationship between Product table and Sales Detail table if I add any product in product table appear in Sales Detail table by Id not Name Product , i need appear value in report not id ..